# How to attach a foreign key while saving a form into a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a model for a blog site which contains 4 fields -post_author,post_title,post_content and date_published.

Also, I have a form to add a new post which has 2 fields post_title and post_content. But while I try to add a new post, it shows Error:NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id

My date field in the model is supposed to fill automatic but the User-id which is a foreign key isn't getting filled.

How am I supposed to attach user_id while saving the form?

post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

form for new post:

```
class newPost(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required =True, max_length=30)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','content']
```

view function:

```
@login_required
def newpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = newPost(request.POST or None)
        if post.is_valid():
            #how to add author of this post ??
            post.save()
            messages.success(request,f'New blog post added. Add more if you want')
            return redirect('blog-newpost')
    else:
        post = newPost()
    context = {'title':'New Post','post': post}
    return render(request,'blog/newpost.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

```py
@login_required
def newpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = newPost(request.POST or None)
        if post.is_valid():
            #how to add author of this post ??
            # post.save()
            title   = post.cleaned_data['title']
            content = post.cleaned_data['content']
            new_post= Post.objects.get_or_create(
                title=title, 
                content=content, 
                author=request.user
            )
            new_post.save()
            messages.success(request,f'New blog post added. Add more if you want')
            return redirect('blog-newpost')
    else:
        post = newPost()
    context = {'title':'New Post','post': post}
    return render(request,'blog/newpost.html',context)
```

**EDIT**: this one may also works

```py
@login_required
def newpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = newPost(request.POST or None)
        if post.is_valid():
            #how to add author of this post ??
            new_post = post.save(commit=False)
            new_post.author = request.user
            new_post.save()
            messages.success(request,f'New blog post added. Add more if you want')
            return redirect('blog-newpost')
    else:
        post = newPost()
    context = {'title':'New Post','post': post}
    return render(request,'blog/newpost.html',context)
```

Comment: 2nd way did work, thankyou.

In 1st method , the error was 'cannot save as a tuple', coz we pass tuple instead of dict I guess

.Also I tried class based views, which also worked